# CPU-Z single channel but shows 2 ram cards

Tags: memory, ramdisk, cpu-z

So today i decided to add another RAM card to my laptop.

I had 1 8GB PC3-12800 (800MHz) already installed
I added another 1 4GB PC3-12800  (800MHz).

Windows shows that i only have 8GB of ram available.

[image]

But CPU-Z Show me that i have 12GB of ram available BUT says SINGLE mode.
[image]

Speccy also shows 12 GB of RAM
[image]

These are some more details about the ram sticks. I noticed that one is using 1.5V and the other is using 1.35V. Does this matter?

[image]
[image]

And my last question is how do i make windows detect my other ram stick?

Comment: You have confirmed you are running in a supported memory configuration?  How much memory does the firmware see when you boot to it?

Comment: " I noticed that one is using 1.5V and the other is using 1.35V. Does this matter?" - It can matter, if the memory is unable to be operate, at the lower voltage.  Your memory channel should be dual not single have you tried changing it?

Comment: @Ramhound My BIOS says 8 sadly enough. But i've searched my laptop on the internet and it sais it supports up to 16 GB.
And the second question
How can i change this? I've not found anything in the bios to change it.

Comment: If your firmware indicates 8GB then you are using an incompatible 4 GB memory module.

Comment: You'd have been safer to get another identical to the one you had. Mix'n'match only works with bags of candy.

Comment: @Ramhound how do i know when its compatible bcause i have another one laying around.

Comment: @Ramhound and if i should buy one extra what should i look out for?

Comment: @Ramhound thank you for helping! I put the other one in and that one was 1.35V that one worked fine! please pur somthing in the answer box so i can accept it :)